# jQuery insert a table object after a table in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Maybe I did not explain my question clearly, and if you think my question is not necessary, at least show me where I can see similar solution, please!. From my point of view, the IE7 comparability issue should be addressed.

I have question about how to insert a table object (class='b') after an existing table (class='a') by jQuery in IE7 (everything looks well in IE8 or Chrome). Can anyone give me some suggestions on the below code?

```
// This is the existing table
<table class='a' align="center">
<tr><th><label for="id_S">Number of modeled stages:</label></th><td><select name="S" id="id_S">
<option value="">Please choose</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select></td></tr>
</table>   //I would like to insert a table class='b' right after this </table> tag

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('<table class="b" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Matrix:</th></tr></table>').appendTo('.a'); //this works in IE8 but not in IE7

})
</script>

// The following code works in IE7, but it messed up the layout

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('<table class="leslie" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Matrix:</th></tr></table>').appendTo('.a td:last');    //this works in IE7, once I changed it to tr:last, it does not work again.

})
</script>
```

## Update

I tried a even simpler case. In IE7, I am able to see the alert message, but could not see the added table row. It seems like IE7 could not show the extra HTML table, but could process the JavaScript code.

```
<script>
$('<table class="b" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Lesile Matrix:</th></tr></table>').appendTo('.a');    
alert('s')
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have a table with a class of "table".  Also, you don't have a table end tag for the table you are trying to add.  Does that fix it?

Comment: @overherenow: no.. the problem still exist.

Comment: This might be a shot in the dark, but wrap the 'tr' tags in the 'tbody' tag.  But I would suggest making it real simple then adding into it.  Maybe just append the table, with no attributes, to see if the table is appended.  Also I would use the 'insertAfter' that Abraham suggested though because .append makes the table a child of the other table.  I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('<table class="leslie" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Matrix:</th></tr></table>').insertAfter('.table');
```

Comment: I'll look more at this later.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not right.  First, you don't have an element with a class of "table".  So that's why the appendTo doesn't work.  It has a class of "a".  Then for the appendTo's, the table you are trying to add doesn't end with a "`</table>`"  Also, I took Abe's advice and changed the appendTo to insertAfter.

Check out your fixed code here: http://jsfiddle.net/YUCDf/1/

Comment: I have fixed those typos. My code works in IE8 or Chrome, but does not work in IE7.

Comment: I tried your approach. But insertAfter does not work for my website in IE7 mode. Though the similar code works well in fiddle open in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it like this? just storing the whole markup in a string and appending to a?

```
var x = '<table class="b" border="0" align="center"><tr><th width="5">Lesile Matrix:</th></tr></table>';
$('.a').append(x);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nVFa5/

Comment: For the table the <th> and <td> are in the same row. So I do not need to add </tr><tr>. i tried the string method, which worked in IE8 not in IE7. Thanks!